# How to Calculate Impermanent Loss in Uniswap v3 Pool Given Burn/Mint/Swap/Collect Data

Tags: uniswapv3

I am trying to compute the total Impermanent Loss by liquidity provider in a given Uniswap v3 Pool given all the Burn/Mint/Collect/Swap events in the pool. Is there a way to do this?